# How to count the number of lines in a CSV before printing the items?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, read.csv

```
with open("C:/Users/number-UK.csv") as csvfile:
    # read csv
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    # print the number of items/rows in the csv file
    print("Step 2: Confirm the total numbers:",int(len(list(readCSV)))-1)   
    continue_text = input("Enter anything to continue")

    # skip the headers
    next(readCSV, None)  

    i=0
    for each_user in readCSV:
        print(i+1," item:",str(each_user[0]))
        i = i + 1

print("all done!")
```

Above is the code which does not work. When I remove the line below, the code works.

```
print("Step 2: Confirm the total numbers:",int(len(list(readCSV)))-1)
```

I want to count the rows of the csv file before the for loop, anyone knows how to achieve this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Issue is `list(readCSV)' exhaust the reader (so there is no more elements) for your subsequent calls.  One way is to convert readCSV into a list by `readCSV = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','))`, which is okay if the file fits easily into memory.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `list(readCSV)' exhaust the reader so there are no more elements for your subsequent calls.

Two options to remedy.

**Option 1 (use list rather than generator for readCSV)**

```
with open("C:/Users/number-UK.csv") as csvfile:
    # read csv (using list rather than iterator)
    readCSV = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','))

    # print the number of items/rows in the csv file
    print("Step 2: Confirm the total numbers:",int(len(readCSV))-1)   
    continue_text = input("Enter anything to continue")

    # skip the headers
    #next(readCSV, None)  # not used

    i=0
    for each_user in readCSV[1:]:  # start at 1 to skip header
        print(i+1," item:",str(each_user[0]))
        i = i + 1

print("all done!")
```

**Option 2 (reacquire readCSV)**

```
with open("C:/Users/number-UK.csv") as csvfile:
    # read csv
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    # print the number of items/rows in the csv file
    print("Step 2: Confirm the total numbers:",int(len(readCSV))-1)   
    continue_text = input("Enter anything to continue")

    # Reacquire (i.e. reset) readCSV iterator
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    # skip the headers
    next(readCSV, None)  # not used

    i=0
    for each_user in readCSV[1:]:  # start at 1 to skip header
        print(i+1," item:",str(each_user[0]))
        i = i + 1

print("all done!")
```

**Option 3 (using enumerate as)**

As suggested by snakecharmerb

```
 with open("C:/Users/number-UK.csv") as csvfile:
    # read csv (using list rather than iterator)
    readCSV = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','))

    # print the number of items/rows in the csv file
    print("Step 2: Confirm the total numbers:",int(len(readCSV))-1)   
    continue_text = input("Enter anything to continue")

    # skip the headers
    #next(readCSV, None)  # not used (header skipped by using readCSV[1:])

    for i, each_user in enumerate(readCSV[1:], start = 1):# start readCSV at 1 
                                               # to skip header
        print(i," item:",str(each_user[0]))  # i starts at 1, 
                                             # so no need to increment

print("all done!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
count = len(csvfile.readlines()))
f.seek(0)
```

`count` will hold the number of lines in the file. **BE AWARE** of executing `f.seek(0)` to move the file read pointer to the beginning of the file, otherwise you won't read anything else because `readlines()` would have read until the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to load the csv into a pandas dataframe and measure the size of that.

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
print(len(test))
```

You can now find the number of rows before the for loop.